# Why Excel PowerQuery result does not display all of the webpage content?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, screen-scraping

I am screen-scraping a web-page like this one (https://www.bmo.com/main/personal/bank-accounts/savings/interest-rates/) using Excel PowerQuery. The output contains only text fields, and not the numbers (no interest rates). I am trying to get account names (tiers) and associated interest rates using this code:

```
Sub OneConnection()
  'Retrieve data
        strConnection = "https://www.bmo.com/main/personal/bank-accounts/savings/interest-rates/"
        strDestination = "Sheet1"
        
       
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
            With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & strConnection _
                , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
                .Name = strDestination
                .FieldNames = True
                .RowNumbers = False
                .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
                .PreserveFormatting = True
                .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
                .BackgroundQuery = True
                .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells 'xlInertDeleteCells
                .SavePassword = False
                .SaveData = True
                .AdjustColumnWidth = True
                .RefreshPeriod = 0
                .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
                .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
                .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
                .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
                .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
                .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
                .WebDisableRedirections = False
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            End With
End Sub
```

Ideally the result will display text fields (account names) and associated interest rates from the bank page. Currently only text is displayed. Screenshot is what I get after running the query.

[image]